# Checking if field begins with X spaces

Tags: excel, vba

This is what i got, but it seems to "ignore" the spaces i give it, any ideas?

```
Sub test()
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, "      *"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Offset(1).SpecialCells(12).EntireRow.Select
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

Edit:
This is how the field(s) im trying to select look like:

```
 (lotsofspaces)         (ID)        (Description) 
                     1-123454-154 - Hello World
```

Comment: I think Excel always ignores leading spaces in filter condition. As a workaround you can create extra column with formula `=LEFT(A2,X)=REPT(" ",X)` or use advanced filter with similar formula.

Comment: have you considered any alternatives. Like trimming the cell or using the length of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Excel uses the tilde (~) as a marker to indicate that the next character is a literal. Try using

```
.AutoFilter 1, "~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~*"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply!, but sadly this just selects the last row, which is empty. This is how the rows im trying to select look like:

(lotsofspaces) (ID) (Description)

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround based on an idea by [srj19](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/468791-possible-filter-forced-leading-trailing-space-chars.html).

Replace `X` number contiguous spaces with coloured spaces, then filter by colour.